# C# Getting Unreachable Code Detected when using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, arduino-uno

I am doing an Arduino project where I am sending data through the serial port and reading it on the PC.  I have a simple C# code written that I can view the data, but I would like to write it to a text file and if possible, execute another program from a certain string read from the Arduino.

Following is the c# code that does read the data, but I am getting a Unreachable Code Detected when using StreamWriter.  Your help is appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace GDC_IoT_Reader
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = "Com4";
        myport.Open();

        while(true)
        {
            string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(data_rx);

        }
        // Write this info to text file

        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"serialdata.txt");

       {
            SW.WriteLine(myport);
        }
        SW.Close();
    }

   }
```

}

Comment: When do you exit your `while` loop? The condition is always `true`.

Comment: I don't want to sound patronising, but if you had actually tried to run through this code, you would have spotted the issue very quickly. Perhaps you should be running through some basic C# tutorials before writing more advanced code?

Comment: I understand.  As stated, I ran the code without trying to write it to a file and it works fine.  But I am trying to learn how to write it to file and then react to what is in the file.  As I stated at the beginning, I am a newbie in C#.

Comment: I have gone through at least 20 tutorials

Comment: I think I understand the error now...I thought it couldn't find StreamWriter but it in fact cannot find the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have infinite `while` loop:

```
while(true)
{
    string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
}
```

Since you don't set any condition to finish the loop and don't have `break` statement inside this loop it will never finish it and all code after this loop is unreachable.

You have to set some condition, i.e. read 10 lines:

```
int line = 0
while(line < 10) // condition to finish
{
    string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
    line += 1;
}
```

Or you can `break` your loop when you read some specific data:

```
while(true)
{
    string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
    if (data_rx == "exit")
    {
        break;      // break loop
    }
}
```

To write line to file inside loop:

```
StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"serialdata.txt");
while(true)
{
    string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
    SW.WriteLine(data_rx);       // write to file
    if (data_rx == "exit")
    {
        break;      // break loop            
    }
}
SW.Close();
```

Comment: It compiles fine and reads the data fine but doesn't save it to a file...any ideas?

Comment: while (true)
            {
                string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
                if (data_rx == "LOUD NOISE DETECTED")
                {
                    break;      // break loop
                }
            }

        
            // Write this info to text file

            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"serialdata.txt");

          
          
                SW.WriteLine(myport);    
            
          
            SW.Close();

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out how to post the code to be viewed properly.

Comment: @BradJarrett, do you want to write to file all lines read inside `while` loop?

Comment: No, just when it finds the line "LOUD NOISE DETECTED".  I am eventually going to add a time stamp so it would look like this: "LOUD NOISE DETECTED 20170303120122"  which is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)

Comment: @BradJarrett, see edited answer. If you want to write only last line, put this line `SW.WriteLine(data_rx);` right before `break` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.  I am having problems with Visual Studio all of a sudden, do a re-install.  I will let you know if this works.

Comment: Roma, It compiles and runs fine but no file is ever created or data is stored.   Is there an email I can chat with you on? I would be happy to pay you for your help...trying to get this project done and very new at c#.

Comment: Roma, actually, it is writing the file..but it is blank...looking into the issue now

Comment: @BradJarrett, your file should be created in `bin/Debug/`. Is there your file? Have you tried to debug?

Comment: StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"serialdata.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
                SW.WriteLine(data_rx);
                if (data_rx == "LOUD NOISE DETECTED!")
                {
                    

                  break;      // break loop

                }
            }

            SW.Close();

Comment: @BradJarrett, Did you get "LOUD NOISE DETECTED!" in console?

Comment: To clarify...Each time I start debug, it updates the timestamp on the file...not each time there is an event.

Comment: Yes, it shows in the console as does every line that Arduino sends.

Comment: @BradJarrett, and this is the last line?

Comment: Correct, it is the last line, then it appears to  have a carriage return as it goes to the next line....do I need to code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `while(true)` loop is unreachable - you need some way to terminate the loop. E.g., if a specific value is read from the socket, or if it's closed.

Comment: Can you give me an example?  I have data string coming in that says "Loud Noise Detected!".  So once that comes in I should terminate the loop?